# I wave when you don't, and when you do

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

I wave when you don't, and when you do,
Only because I look up to you.
Watch as I dance with my jelly-like bones,
That can't be broken by sticks or stones.
My eyes go deep when you closely stare,
But a kiss would leave you gasping for air.
Make me at one with the misty moon,
And lo and behold, we'll separate soon.

Who/what am I?

Comment: Is "low and behold" a clue or is it supposed to be "lo and behold"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Your reflection cast on water?

I wave when you don't, and when you do,

> ripples and waves?

Only because I look up to you.

> from the surface of the water

Watch as I dance with my jelly-like bones,

> ripples again

That can't be broken by sticks or stones.

> Sticks and stones will break the surface of the water but not your reflection maybe?

My eyes go deep when you closely stare,

> look close and you'll see into the water through your own eyes

But a kiss would leave you gasping for air.

> also known as drowning

Make me at one with the misty moon,

> Step away and instead see the reflection of the sky?

And lo and behold, we'll separate soon.

> your reflection gone...?

Answer (score 1):

> A wave? Or the sea?

Because:

I wave when you don't, and when you do,

> Well the sea has waves which will be if you wave or not

Only because I look up to you.

> Not sure, most of us are above sea level

Watch as I dance with my jelly-like bones,

> The sea moves and 'dances' with its 'bones' made of water

That can't be broken by sticks or stones.

> Water cant be broken by sticks or stones

My eyes go deep when you closely stare,

> Reference to the depth pf the sea?

But a kiss would leave you gasping for air.

> A) Kissing the sea would be very salty and B) You can't breathe in water, you need air

Make me at one with the misty moon,

> Moon controls the tides

And low and behold, we'll separate soon.

> Not sure